# How to search for any question with one or more of a set of tags AND a specific tag

Tags: support, search

I'd like to construct a complex search that lists all questions with any of one set of tags and another tag.

For instance, I want to find questions tagged with "php" and any of a set of tags including [application-x, application-y, application-z].

Comment: There's also [data.se] aka SEDE though my experience recently has been that it times out if I try anything fancy.  (Probably because my SQL sucks.)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The new nav seems to be able to do this with with `is:q [tag] and [tag] or [tag]`. For example, [`is:q [swift] and [python] or [ruby]`](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=is%3Aq+%5Bswift%5D+and+%5Bpython%5D+or+%5Bruby%5D)

Comment: What is the precedence of operators? Does it search for `[swift]+[iphone] or [swift]+[ios]` or `[swift]+[iphone] or [ios]`?

Comment: @A.L Through typical order of operations, it would be the second one.

Comment: Following the link from your "for example", search appears to not understand AND, but does understand OR. [swift] AND [iphone] OR [ios] results in questions tagged iphone or ios + swift, which contain the word and. Additionally, the left side appears to only allow a single tag. To return `[swift]+[iphone] or [ios]`, you need to search [`[ios] OR [swift] [iphone]`](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=is%3Aq+%5Bios%5D+OR+%5Biphone%5D+%5Bswift%5D)

Comment: @A.L or takes precedence

Comment: @Daniel I presume because undo assumed new nav, if you remove and it gives you the same tagged results, that contains swift and either iphone or ios.

Comment: @Braiam Presume what you like. I tested it. YMMV.

Comment: @Daniel the new nav accepts "and" keywords. I tested it too...

Comment: Perhaps the answer could clarify this only works for users participating in the [new nav beta](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/new-nav/info).

Comment: undo, if you are using is:q, forcing the /search, /search doesn't understand "and" as keyword. Only the [new nav understands "and"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/javascript%20and%20jquery)

Comment: @Braiam The link given (changed it to be more extreme) works fine in incognito.

Comment: "results found containing: and; tagged with: python or  ruby swift; search options: questions only" that's the result. The link tries to search for questions that contain "and", but this is not necessary.